# How to use the enigmatic-puzzle tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't really understand the true meaning of the [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) tag. Its tag info is:

> Puzzles where the genre or solving strategy of the puzzle is not explicitly stated; puzzles where the puzzler must deduce what type of puzzle it is.

My interpretation:

> 1. There are too many tags I want to put but there's not enough space. I am not listing them out.
> 2. There are some suitable tags for this puzzle, but I don't want to state them because I think that would spoil the puzzle.

Can anyone please clear my doubt? Many thanks!

---

Note:

1. Can anyone help me format my list formatting? Thanks! [*Done. -- gjm*]
2. This is my first PSE Meta Question. Any constructive edits and suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Neither part of your interpretation quite matches how I think the tag is used in practice, or how I think it should be used.

I take [enigmatic-puzzle] to mean: "The solver's first task, which is a non-trivial puzzle in itself, is to work out what sort of thing they have to do."

For instance, take a look at [the highest-rated enigmatic-puzzle at present](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen). The puzzle consists of a couple of highly mysterious images, and some equally mysterious text ... but whatever are you meant to do? Well, there are a couple of things to grab onto, and the first thing you solve leads to another thing, and another leads to another, and gradually the whole truth emerges.

Imagine a version of this that *wasn't* an [enigmatic-puzzle]. It would need to explain what actual puzzles needed solving and what sort of puzzles they were, and it would be much more straightforward and much less fun.

Comment: Here is an example: [This is a puzzle that the creator didn't clearly tell you what you have to do.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48948/grid-thirty-six/)

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48948/grid-thirty-six/77514#77514).
The [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) tag tells you that the creator didn't clearly tell you what you have to do.
If the tag is absent, the question may look like this:

> Don't rotate for everything. Solve the ACROSS/DOWN clue in the red box and fill it into the blue box...
>   ... ...
>   [picture]